# color does not want to convert automatically

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb, hsl, converters

I'm a javascript noob.

I made a hsl colorpicker and I would like to convert the hsl color automatically to rgb and hex. I found a piece of code from w3schools that I would like to use for this.
The only problem is that the color code is only converted when the color code is entered manually.

I would like the colors to be automatically converted as soon as the color is changed with the oniput function in the sliders.
I just do not know how to change the code for this.

Here is the code:

```js
// below color converter
    // Make sure to include https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3color.js
        var colora1, rgba1, hexa1;
    

        $('#colora1').on('keyup', function() {
          colora1 = w3color($(this).val());
          
          if(colora1.valid) {
            hexa1  = colora1.toHexString();
         
            $('#hexa1').html(hexa1);
            
            if(colora1.opacity == 1) {
              rgba1  = colora1.toRgbString();
              
              $('#rgbNamea1').text('Rgb');
              $('#hslNamea1').text('Hex');
            } 
            else {
              rgba1  = colora1.toRgbaString();
              hexa1  = colora1.toHslaString();
              
              $('#rgbNamea1').text('Rgba');
              $('#hslNamea1').text('Hsla');
            }
              
            $('#rgba1').html(rgba1);
            $('#hexa1').html(hexa1);
          }
          
        });
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}
#view-color{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.colors{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
#colora1, textarea{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="view-color" style="background-color: hsl(100, 100%, 50%)"></div><br>
hue<br>
<input oninput="changeColor()" type="range" id="hue" max="360" min="0" value="100"><br>
sat<br>
<input oninput="changeColor()" type="range" id="sat" max="100" min="0" value="100"><br>
light<br>
<input oninput="changeColor()" type="range" id="light" max="100" min="0" value="50">
    
<div class="colors">
  input<br>
    <input id="colora1" value="red" type="text">
  output rgb<br>
          <textarea id="rgba1" readonly>rgb(255, 0, 0)</textarea>
  output hex<br>
          <textarea id="hexa1" readonly>#ff0000</textarea>
 </div>
<script>
  function changeColor(){
    hue   = document.getElementById('hue').value;
    sat   = document.getElementById('sat').value;
    light = document.getElementById('light').value;
    hsl   = 'hsl('+hue+', '+sat+'%, '+light+'%)';

    document.getElementById('view-color').style.backgroundColor = hsl;
    document.getElementById('colora1').value = hsl;
}
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3color.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get hex and rgb color values inside `changeColor` function and to assign them to corresponding inputs like you do with hsl (`document.getElementById('colora1').value = hsl;`). Also you need to change

```
$('#rgba1').html(rgba1);
$('#hexa1').html(hexa1);
```

to

```
$('#rgba1').val(rgba1);
$('#hexa1').val(hexa1);
```

inside `keyup` callback function.

```js
// below color converter
    // Make sure to include https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3color.js
        var colora1, rgba1, hexa1;
    

        $('#colora1').on('keyup', function () {
          colora1 = w3color($(this).val());
          
          if(colora1.valid) {
            hexa1  = colora1.toHexString();
         
            $('#hexa1').html(hexa1);
            
            if(colora1.opacity == 1) {
              rgba1  = colora1.toRgbString();
              
              $('#rgbNamea1').text('Rgb');
              $('#hslNamea1').text('Hex');
            } 
            else {
              rgba1  = colora1.toRgbaString();
              hexa1  = colora1.toHslaString();
              
              $('#rgbNamea1').text('Rgba');
              $('#hslNamea1').text('Hsla');
            }
 
            $('#rgba1').val(rgba1);
            $('#hexa1').val(hexa1);
          }
          
        });
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}
#view-color{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.colors{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
#colora1, textarea{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="view-color" style="background-color: hsl(100, 100%, 50%)"></div><br>
hue<br>
<input oninput="changeColor()" type="range" id="hue" max="360" min="0" value="100"><br>
sat<br>
<input oninput="changeColor()" type="range" id="sat" max="100" min="0" value="100"><br>
light<br>
<input oninput="changeColor()" type="range" id="light" max="100" min="0" value="50">
    
<div class="colors">
  input<br>
    <input id="colora1" value="red" type="text">
  output rgb<br>
          <textarea id="rgba1" readonly>rgb(255, 0, 0)</textarea>
  output hex<br>
          <textarea id="hexa1" readonly>#ff0000</textarea>
 </div>
<script>
  function changeColor(){
    hue   = document.getElementById('hue').value;
    sat   = document.getElementById('sat').value;
    light = document.getElementById('light').value;
    hsl   = 'hsl('+hue+', '+sat+'%, '+light+'%)';
    
    
    color = w3color(hsl);

    document.getElementById('view-color').style.backgroundColor = hsl;
    document.getElementById('colora1').value = hsl;
    document.getElementById('hexa1').value = color.toHexString();
    document.getElementById('rgba1').value = color.toRgbString();
}
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3color.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanx Volodymyr :)
You helped me a lot

Comment: @splintermark77 Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct and/or upvote if it solved your issue. It will show other users that the answer is correct and they can check it

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you trigger the update of the two last fields only on "keyup" of colora1, so it will not be updated in any other case. You can fix that by calling the function when at the end of the changeColor.

You js will be something like :

```
    $('#colora1').on('keyup', function() {
        propagateColor();
    }

    function propagateColor() {
        var colora1, rgba1, hexa1;
        colora1 = w3color($(this).val());

        if(colora1.valid) {
            hexa1  = colora1.toHexString();

            $('#hexa1').html(hexa1);

            if(colora1.opacity == 1) {
                rgba1  = colora1.toRgbString();

                $('#rgbNamea1').text('Rgb');
                $('#hslNamea1').text('Hex');
            } 
            else {
                rgba1  = colora1.toRgbaString();
                hexa1  = colora1.toHslaString();

                $('#rgbNamea1').text('Rgba');
                $('#hslNamea1').text('Hsla');
            }

            $('#rgba1').html(rgba1);
            $('#hexa1').html(hexa1);
        }

    });

    function changeColor(){
        hue   = document.getElementById('hue').value;
        sat   = document.getElementById('sat').value;
        light = document.getElementById('light').value;
        hsl   = 'hsl('+hue+', '+sat+'%, '+light+'%)';

        document.getElementById('view-color').style.backgroundColor = hsl;
        document.getElementById('colora1').value = hsl;
        propagateColor()
    }
```